# Find root (limit of integration) in numerical integration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

I'm trying to rewrite a Mathematica code to construct the equipopulated rings:

```
Nr = 5; (*radial modes*)


DF0[JJ_] := Exp[-JJ]; (*distribution function of long action*)
Jmax = 20; (* max action for numerical cuts*)
CF = NIntegrate[DF0[II], {II, 0, Jmax}];
DF[JJ_] := DF0[JJ]/CF;

bJ = Array[0, Nr + 1];
bJ[[1]] = 0.;
bJ[[Nr + 1]] = Jmax;

For[ir = 2, ir < Nr + 1, ir++,
  bb = bJ[[ir - 1]];
  bJ[[ir]] = 
   Jroot /. 
    FindRoot[
     Integrate[DF[JJ], {JJ, bb, Jroot}] == 1/Nr, {Jroot, bb + 1/(Nr DF[bb])}];
  ];

bJ = Re[bJ];


(* Finding actions aJ of the thin rings: *)

aJ = Array[0, Nr];
For[ir = 1, ir < Nr + 1, ir++,
  aJ[[ir]] = NIntegrate[J Nr DF[J], {J, bJ[[ir]], bJ[[ir + 1]]}];
  ];

aJ = Re[aJ];
rr = Sqrt[2 aJ]; (*radii of the rings*)


NHTRingsPlot = 
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{rr[[i]] Cos[u], rr[[i]] Sin[u]}, {i, 1, Nr}]], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue},(*PlotLabel\[Rule]"Nested Rings",*) AxesLabel -> {"z", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(z\)]\)"},LabelStyle -> Directive[{FontSize -> 16}]]
```

to Python:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad

Nr = 5.    
Jmax = 20. 

CF = math.ceil(scipy.integrate.quad(lambda II : math.exp(-II), 0, Jmax)[0]) 

bJ = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])
bJ[0] = 0.
bJ[Nr] = Jmax

def func():
    func = quad(lambda JJ : (math.exp(-JJ) / CF), bb, Jroot) - 1/Nr
    for i in bJ:
        i=1
        if i < Nr:
            i += 1
            bb = bJ[i]
            bJ = np.roots(func, Jroots, bb + CF/(Nr * math.exp(-bb)))
            bJ.append()
        return bJ
```

The problem is with func:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'

and 
with bb:

NameError: name 'bb' is not defined

I just started to learn Python and would be appreciated if somebody of you could help me with it.

Comment: For those of us that might be Mathematica challenged, add some comments to your Mathematica code or describe what it is doing or point us to the algorithm you are trying to implement.  Also, saying `I'm stuck`  isn't very helpful - what is wrong with the results.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with what you have written. Since I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish this won't be an *answer* but I'll point out the problems that I see.  You should probably spend some time with [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html) in the documentation.

```
CF = math.ceil(scipy.integrate.quad(lambda II : math.exp(-II), 0, Jmax)[0])
```

The right hand side of the assignment will evaluate to `1.0` so CF will always be `1.0`

```
def func():
    func = .....
```

You begin a function definition for a function named `func` then you immediately assign something else to the name `func`.  Take a look at [Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) and [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

[`scipy.integrate.quad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#general-integration-quad) returns a tuple, you cannot perform a math operation (`- 1/Nr`) on a tuple.

```
NameError: name 'bb' is not defined
```

You haven't assigned anything to `bb` yet so it is not defined.  If you want to create a *partial* function for use later with different values for `bb`, have a look at [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial).  Another alternative would be to define the function later in the code after the point where `bb` is programmatically changed.

```
>>> print bb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    print bb
NameError: name 'bb' is not defined
>>> # assign 1 to bb
>>> bb = 1
>>> print bb
1
>>>
```

It is very hard to decipher what you are trying to do with your `for` loop (`for i in bJ:`) but you are not using it correctly, [`for` Statements](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), [The `for` Statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) - here is a quick example:

```
>>> a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
>>> for n in a:
    print n


1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
>>>
```

`for i in bJ:` assigns successive items/elements of `bJ` to `i` on each iteration then in the `for` loop suite you assign different values to `i` which is wrong. You are doing this

```
>>> for c in 'abcde':
    print 'c is ', c
    c = 2
    print 'now c is ', c

c is  a
now c is  2
c is  b
now c is  2
c is  c
now c is  2
c is  d
now c is  2
c is  e
now c is  2
>>>
```

One really nice thing about Python is you can try things out in the shell and see how they work or don't work.